IBM MQ C# .Net with SSL cannot find my certificate
I have simple console app which should connect to IBM MQ with their .Net driver. Here is piece of the code with my settings:
MQEnvironment.SSLKeyRepository = "*USER";
MQEnvironment.SSLCipherSpec = "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256";
MQEnvironment.SSLCertRevocationCheck = false;
MQEnvironment.CertificateLabel = "VRZLBGZ";
MQEnvironment.UserId = "VRZLBGZ";
MQEnvironment.Password = "hidden";
MQEnvironment.Channel = channel;

Hashtable connectionProperties = new Hashtable();
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.TRANSPORT_PROPERTY, MQC.TRANSPORT_MQSERIES_MANAGED);
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CONNECTION_NAME_PROPERTY, "hidden value");
connectionProperties.Add(MQC.CONNECT_OPTIONS_PROPERTY, MQC.MQCNO_RECONNECT_Q_MGR);
MQQueueManager qMgr = new MQQueueManager("QSBVBT01", connectionProperties);

I have installed certificate in windows, it is visible in certificate manager in my personal certificates and I even set Friendly Name for it VRZLBGZ.
When I run certutil -store My i can see it:
================ Certificate 2 ================
Serial Number: 220000be42c6db942238cb25f000020000be42
Issuer: CN=hidden value, O=hidden value, C=CZ
 NotBefore: 5/2/2024 1:02 PM
 NotAfter: 5/2/2026 1:02 PM
Subject: CN=VRZLBGZ, O=hidden value
Non-root Certificate
Template: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.8.16659364.9511224.6767036.10761918.7007572.160.14543026.1837566
Cert Hash(sha1): 79ed4c68f93675d4f3b09df79bdad365bfbba0c1
  Key Container = {CDC32A72-FC92-487E-9F4A-62B52167360D}
  Provider = Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider
Private key is NOT exportable
Encryption test passed

But when I run my console app with trace, i can see this:
000001A3 14:23:23.033142   15580.1     Created an instance of SSLStreams
000001A4 14:23:23.033157   15580.1     Setting current certificate store as 'User'
000001A5 14:23:23.033163   15580.1     Windows/Mac so use My Store  & CurrentStore
000001A6 14:23:23.033168   15580.1     Created store object to access certificates
000001A7 14:23:23.035052   15580.1     Opened store
000001A8 14:23:23.035074   15580.1     Accessing certificate - VRZLBGZ
000001A9 14:23:23.035127   15580.1     Number of certificates in the store:0

What I'm doing wrong? Why IBM MQ in my console app sees 0 certificates in the store?
I even tried to extend my console app to write out certificates, like this:
X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);  // Use StoreLocation.LocalMachine if applicable
store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

foreach (X509Certificate2 cert in store.Certificates)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Certificate: " + cert.FriendlyName);
    if (cert.FriendlyName == "VRZLBGZ")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Found the certificate:" + cert.FriendlyName);
    }
}

store.Close();

The output is as expected:
Certificate:
Certificate:
Certificate: VRZLBGZ
Found the certificate:VRZLBGZ


Change the friendly name to ibmwebspheremqvrzlbgz.  The last part should be the username your application is running as in lower case.

@JoshMc that is one of things I tried in the beginning. Tried again, doesn't work.

What version of the MQ dll are you using?

@JoshMc latest 9.4.0

Did you get a MQRC 2393?  The queue manger AMQERR01.LOG would also indicate the cipher mismatch.  Since you are using manged mode you cannot specify a specific cipher on the client side other than for the client to determine the protocol to use like TLSv1.2.  It it best with managed mode .net clients to specify ANY_TLS12_OR_HIGHER on the queue manger SVRCONN channel, this way it can negotiate to the highest common cipher and you do not need to worry about changing it in the future.

@JoshMc thanks for explanation. Anyway in was mistake on other side, because they gave us a list of parameters.

In the end the problem was different cipher suite.
I've received outdated documentation from people who are taking care of IBM MQ instance on which we were trying to connect.
Anyway maybe this will help someone. IBM MQ has not very verbose and specific error messages and codes. Because it was not obvious it is a problem with cipher suite, just SSL in general. The library picked the certificate from windows certificate storage but because of cipher suite difference it assumed it's not right one. THerefore the 0 in trace.
